# Improving Poker Odds Calculator

Tags: python

This code accepts input from the user on a game of Texas Hold Em Poker.
It then reports back the odds of winning against a single opponent at each betting stage.
The calculation needs to process (50 choose 5) * (45 choose 2) for the pre-flop calculation.
The way I know this can be done fast is to randomly sample these possibilities and report back a estimate of the odds, this is how I see online/mobile app calculators do it anyway.

I'm looking for:

1) any other method to show the odds faster, maybe saving some pre-computed values and doing a lookup?

2) if this isn't possible, any way to speed up the code that checks who is winning the hand for each possibility

```
from itertools import compress, product, combinations
from random import sample

suits = ['s','d','h','c']
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

deck = [str(card[0]) + card[1] for card in list(product(values, suits))]

hand_dict ={
        0:  "Straight Flush",
        1:  "Quads",
        2:  "Full House",
        3:  "Flush",
        4:  "Straight",
        5:  "Trips",
        6:  "Two Pair",
        7:  "One Pair",
        8:  "High Card"
        }

card_dict = {
        "A": 1,
        "K": 13,
        "Q": 12,
        "J": 11,
        "T": 10,
          1: "A",
         14: "A",
         13: "K",
         12: "Q",
         11: "J"
        }

def rotate(l, n):
    return l[n:] + l[:n]

def hasConsecutive(arr, amount):
    last = 0
    count = 0
    arr = [int(txt[:-1]) for txt in arr]
    if any([num == 1 for num in arr]):
        arr = arr + [14]
    arr = sorted(arr, reverse = True)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] != (last - 1) :
            count = 0
        last = arr[i]
        count += 1
        if amount <= count:
            return True, arr[i] + 4
    return False, 0

def getHand(held_cards, table_cards):
    all_cards = sorted(held_cards + table_cards)

    all_cards = [str(card_dict[card[0].upper()]) + card[-1] if card[0].isalpha() else card for card in all_cards]
    card_vals = sorted([int(txt[:-1]) for txt in all_cards], reverse = True)
    hands = [8]
    hand_cards = [sorted([14 if card == 1 else card for card in card_vals], reverse = True)[:5]]
    for suit in suits:
        suited = [suit in txt for txt in all_cards]
        if sum(suited) >= 5:
            hands.append(3)
            hand_cards.append(list(compress(card_vals, suited))[:5])
            straight, high = hasConsecutive(list(compress(all_cards, suited)), 5)
            if straight :
                hands.append(0)
                hand_cards.append([high])
            break

    straight, high = hasConsecutive(all_cards, 5)
    if straight :
        hands.append(4)
        hand_cards.append([high])

    for value in rotate(sorted(values, reverse = True),-1):
        dups = [num == value for num in card_vals]
        count_dups = sum(dups)
        if count_dups == 4:
            hands.append(1)
            hand_cards.append([[list(compress(card_vals, dups))[0]] + [list(compress(card_vals, [not i for i in dups]))[:1]]])
        elif count_dups == 3:
            hands.append(5)
            hand_cards.append([[list(compress(card_vals, dups))[0]] + list(compress(card_vals, [not i for i in dups]))[:2]])
            for value in rotate(sorted(values, reverse = True),-1):
                if value != list(compress(card_vals, dups))[0]:
                    more_dups = [num == value for num in card_vals]
                    count_dups = sum(more_dups)
                    if count_dups == 2:
                        hands.append(2)
                        hand_cards.append([[list(compress(card_vals, dups))[0]] + [list(compress(card_vals, more_dups))[0]]])
        elif count_dups == 2:
            hands.append(7)
            hand_cards.append([[list(compress(card_vals, dups))[0]] + list(compress(card_vals, [not i for i in dups]))[:3]])
            for value in rotate(sorted(values, reverse = True),-1):
                if value != list(compress(card_vals, dups))[0]:
                    more_dups = [num == value for num in card_vals]
                    count_dups = sum(more_dups)
                    if count_dups == 2:
                        hands.append(6)
                        hand_cards.append([[list(compress(card_vals, dups))[0]] + [list(compress(card_vals, more_dups))[0]] + [list(compress(card_vals, [not (dups[i] or more_dups[i]) for i in range(len(dups))]))[0]]])

    best_hand = min(hands)
    hand = hand_cards[hands.index(best_hand)]

    return best_hand, hand

def compareHands(our_hand, our_highs, opp_hand, opp_highs):
    if our_hand < opp_hand:
        return "W"
    elif our_hand > opp_hand:
        return "L"
    elif our_hand == opp_hand:
        for i in range(len(our_highs)):
            if our_highs[i] > opp_highs[i]:
                return "W"
            elif our_highs[i] < opp_highs[i]:
                return "L"
        return "D"

def Check_Odds(our_cards, table_cards = []):
    unseen_deck = [card for card in deck if not (card in (our_cards + table_cards))]
    results = []
    unseen_combs = list(combinations(unseen_deck,5-len(table_cards)))
    for tableCards in sample(unseen_combs, int(min(1e2,len(unseen_combs)))):
        undrawn_deck = [card for card in unseen_deck if not (card in list(tableCards))]
        undrawn_combs = list(combinations(undrawn_deck,2))
        our_hand, our_highs = getHand(our_cards, table_cards + list(tableCards))
        for oppCards in sample(undrawn_combs, int(min(1e3,len(undrawn_combs)))):
            opp_hand, opp_highs = getHand(list(oppCards), table_cards + list(tableCards))
            results.append(compareHands(our_hand, our_highs, opp_hand, opp_highs))

    wins = sum([result == "W" for result in results])
    total = len(results)
    odds = wins/total
    return odds

def Request_Card(place, num = -1):
    if num == -1:
        ind = ""
    else:
        ind = str(num+1)
    inp = input(place + " card " + ind + " is:")
    request_new = False
    if inp[0].isalpha():
        if not(inp[0].upper() in card_dict):
            request_new = True
        else:
            inp = str(card_dict[inp[0].upper()]) + inp[-1] if inp[0].isalpha() else inp   
    if not(inp in deck):
        request_new = True
    if request_new:
        input(place + " card " + str(num+1) + " - Invalid card: Press ENTER to try again")
        inp = Request_Card(place, num)
    return inp

while True:
    Pocket = []
    Table = []
    for i in range(2):
        Pocket = Pocket + [Request_Card("Pocket", i)]
    print(str(round(100*Check_Odds(Pocket),2)) + "%")
    for i in range(3):
        Table = Table + [Request_Card("Flop", i)]
    print(str(round(100*Check_Odds(Pocket, Table),2)) + "%")
    Table = Table + [Request_Card("Turn")]
    print(str(round(100*Check_Odds(Pocket, Table),2)) + "%")
    Table = Table + [Request_Card("River")]
    print(str(round(100*Check_Odds(Pocket, Table),2)) + "%")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a chance that this can be sped up:

```
any([num == 1 for num in arr])
```

Currently, you're going through all of `arr`, then giving the list to `any`. If the first `num` is 1, you're still checking the rest of `num`. Just remove the `[]` and make it a generator expression:

```
any(num == 1 for num in arr)
```

I've found generator expressions to have more overhead than list comprehensions, but they can be faster in "early exit" problems like this.

---

I'm not sure if this is due to trying to avoid mutating the original, but this is likely relatively slow:

```
arr = arr + [14]
```

You're creating a new list here with that, then reassigning it back to `arr`. Unless you want to avoid mutating `arr`, just write:

```
arr.append(14)
```

---

You're calling `sorted` a lot. This involves the creation of a new list which will have some overhead. I didn't test it, but you can likely replace at least some of those calls with a call to `sort` and have the list sorted in place. Creating lists all over the place will add up after awhile.

---

```
if not(inp in deck)
```

Can just be

```
if inp not in deck
```

Which reads a little nicer.

---

Similar to my second point this chunk seems like it's creating a lot of lists:

```
Pocket = []
Table = []
for i in range(2):
    Pocket = Pocket + [Request_Card("Pocket", i)]
print(str(round(100*Check_Odds(Pocket),2)) + "%")
for i in range(3):
    Table = Table + [Request_Card("Flop", i)]
print(str(round(100*Check_Odds(Pocket, Table),2)) + "%")
Table = Table + [Request_Card("Turn")]
print(str(round(100*Check_Odds(Pocket, Table),2)) + "%")
Table = Table + [Request_Card("River")]
print(str(round(100*Check_Odds(Pocket, Table),2)) + "%")
```

Every time you call `+` on a list, you're creating a new list that results from adding the two together. You can see that here:

```
>> l = [1]
>> m = [2]
>> q = l + m
>> q
    [1, 2]
>> q.append(9)
>> q
    [1, 2, 9]
>> l
    [1]
>> m
    [2]
```

Normally this isn't a huge deal, but you're looking for performance suggestions.

Really, you should be using `append` or a similar function to mutate the lists in place unless you have a good reason to constantly create new lists.

---

Please abide by proper [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Variables like `Table` and `Pocket` should be lower case. They aren't class names.

---

Your use of `list(combinations(…))` is probably quite expensive. For example, you have

```
undrawn_combs = list(combinations(undrawn_deck,2))
. . .

for oppCards in sample(undrawn_combs, …):
```

It seems like you're never needing all of the combinations since you're only taking a sample from them. You currently need a list because you do `len(undrawn_combs)` to calculate `k`, but this is all likely quite expensive. I would just have:

```
undrawn_combs = combinations(undrawn_deck,2)
```

Then calculate the length using:

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$

Where `k` is how many elements are in each sub-set, and `n` is the length of the list.

Comment: Thank you! These are all good suggestions and I'm learning a lot! I'll give it a go. If noone comes back with a suggestion of a different method soon I'll accept this answer